# Error installing multi-module project in Maven

Tags: java, maven

Here's what my POM file looks like:

```
  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>my-app</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>


<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-company-id</id>
        <name>my-company-repo</name>
        <url>URL of company's artifactory</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>


  <dependencies>
        <!-- parentDir -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>company.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>company-project</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.82</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- childDir -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>company.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>company-project-child</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.82</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Also, the dependency (see in POM file) I am trying to install is structured as:

```
company.project
      |- parentDir
            |- pom.xml (no jar in parentDir)
      |- childDir
            |- pom.xml
            |- child-project.jar
```

Here's what the POMs in childDir and parentDir  look like:

child:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>company-project</artifactId>
    <groupId>company.project</groupId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>company-project-child</artifactId>
```

parent:

```
<groupId>company.project</groupId>
<artifactId>company-project</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>${revision}</version>

<modules>
    <module>company-project-child</module>
</modules>
```

ERROR:

```
Failed to execute goal on project my-app: Could not resolve dependencies for project 
com.company:my-app:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at company.project: 
company-project-child:jar:1.0.82: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
company.project:company-project-child:jar:1.0.82: Could not find artifact 
company.project:company-project:pom:${revision} in my-company-id (<URL of company's artifactory>)
```

Why can't ${revision} be resolved?

Thanks!

EDIT: The directory structure shown above is actually for the downloaded dependencies in my local repo: .m2/repository/... The original project does have the parent pom.xml a level above the child pom.xml.

Comment: Please add the poms as text in the post not as links etc. The child expects having it's parent one level higher in directory structure which is not the case here.

Comment: It mind be an issue in you pom file. Should be something like ${project.resivsion} https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#properties

Comment: @khmarbaise Please see my edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
The problem was with the versions of the jar I wanted to install. Here's what I did:

->  Manually downloaded the child-project.jar and put it into my local maven repo (~/.m2/repository) 
->  In the local repo, the directory structure looked something like:

```
company
  |- project
      |-  company-project-child
            |-  1.80.1 (version no.)
                  |- company-project-child-1.80.1.jar
                  |- company-project-child-1.80.1.pom
      |-  company-project-parent
            |-  1.80.1
                  |- company-project-parent-1.80.1.pom
```

Now in the child pom, I changed to parent version from `${revision}` to `1.80.1` like so: 
Original:

```
<parent>
   <artifactId>company-project</artifactId>
   <groupId>company.project</groupId>
   <version>${revision}</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>company-project-child</artifactId>
```

Changed to:

```
<parent>
   <artifactId>company-project</artifactId>
   <groupId>company.project</groupId>
   <version>1.80.1</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>company-project-child</artifactId>
```

->  In the same way, I changed the version in parent pom file from `${revision}` to `1.80.1`

->  Now, running `mvn install` works fine!